# AS3. How to save json array from php into sqlite?

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3

i have **JSON Array** data come from **Mysql and Php** , 
i want to store this **JSON Array** in **SQLite** and Get it back Like A **JSON Array**

> this the output of the json array it come from the php

```
{
"task": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "tid": "100",
        "ttitles": "test",
        "stime": "2018-10-08 02:40:28",
        "seentime": null,
        "subject": "Testing",
        "ftime": null,
        "uid": "1101",
        "tsp": "11001"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "tid": "101",
        "ttitles": "tesst",
        "stime": "2018-10-08 02:41:17",
        "seentime": null,
        "subject": "Tessting",
        "ftime": null,
        "uid": "1101",
        "tsp": "110001"
    }
]
}
```

> and this the AS3 code to get the data result from php

```
        public function processTasks():void
    {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        request.url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx/a/tasks.php? 
        empid="+empid;
        request.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", 
        "application/json")];
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, receive);
        loader.load(request);       
    }   
    public function receive(event:Event):void
    {
       // here i want get the Json Array data then store in to SQLite 
       // And get back again as a JSON .
    }
```

Comment: **JSON** format is a **String** (which can be parsed into generic **Object**, which is, in turn, can be stringified back, look https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html for more details). Yet, ultimately, it is just a **String** so you are to write (and retrieve at a later moment) some text data into that SQLite of yours.

Comment: any example please ?

Comment: *Any example please* of what, exactly?

Comment: in the `public function receive(event:Event):void{ }`

Comment: @IbrahimAyyad (1) _`"i want get the Json Array data"`_ did you try something like `myString = event.data;` since JSON data is a **String** as told in first comment? (2) _`"store in to SQLite"`_ what effort (code) [from your research](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=CXrDW8CcNcLOgQbt4qfACg&q=use+php+to+update+mysql&oq=use+php+to+update+mysql) is not working? Maybe we can help fix that if you show us (3) _`"get back again as a JSON"`_ again show code of what you've tried from reading manuals & tutorials that is not working... We can only **help you fix your code**.

Comment: Thanks all , i do already change the result come from the PHP from JSON to String_Array and i save it in SQLite Already and this good for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i do already change the result come from the PHP from JSON to String_Array with 
>    splitByComma(extrnalString:String) , i save it in SQLite Already and this good for me .

Here the Code that work With me ;

```
    public function processTasks():void
    {
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        varSend.url = "http://localhost/a/tasks.php?empid="+empid;
        varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        varSend.data = variables;
        var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
        varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        variables.myrequest = "get_data_array";
        varLoader.load(varSend);
        function completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var returnStr:String = event.target.data.returnString;
            splitByComma(returnStr);
        }
    }   
    public function splitByComma(extrnalString:String):void
    {
        var myArray:Array = extrnalString.split("(||)");
        for(var element:String in myArray){
            i++;
            var innerArray:Array = myArray[element].split("|");
                movie_id = innerArray[0];
                movie_taskid = innerArray[1];
                movie_tasktitles = innerArray[2];
                movie_taskstime = innerArray[3];
                movie_taskseentime = innerArray[4];
                movie_tasksubject = innerArray[5];
                movie_taskftime = innerArray[6];
                movie_taskuid = innerArray[7];
                movie_tasktsp = innerArray[8];
                openDB_to_Insert();
            }
```